# How to send HTTP request with website's IP address instead of user's

Tags: html, http, iframe, ip

I want to implement some security functionality where when a website requests a file from another server and display it to the user, but the HTTP request IP must be set to the website's ip instead of the user's ip.

My first thought was iframes but iframes will use the user's address. Is what I want to do possible, and if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a server-side language to fetch the document from your webserver and display it to the user.

PHP Example:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll do something similar. Because I'm mostly interested for video files I'll use the php stream.